# Process control characters in pexpect output

Tags: python, bash, terminal, pexpect

For example consider this piece of text:

```
 * Starting FTP server vsftpd       [80G /usr/sbin/vsftpd already running.

[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting RPC port mapper daemon rpcbind       [80G 
[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server sshd       [80G 
[74G[ OK ]
]0;root@cc334d73f202: ~root@cc334d73f202:~# curl https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=760868
]0;root@cc334d73f202: ~root@cc334d73f202:~# [K
```

If you were to save this to a file, then run cat command on it, you would get:

```
 * Starting FTP server vsftpd                                                   /usr/sbin/vsftpd already running.
                                                                         [ OK ]
 * Starting RPC port mapper daemon rpcbind                               [ OK ] 
 * Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server sshd                             [ OK ] 
root@cc334d73f202:~# curl https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=760868
root@cc334d73f202:~#
```

I want to somehow convert the existing text to this more readable format. (The output with control characters was obtained from pexpect output). I use `child.logfile_read = f` to capture the pexpect output.

I have tried to delete the control characters, but the text is not as readable as it would be if they were actually processed.

I have also tried `cat file_name > new_file_name` but that does not change anything.

I have looked through pexpect docs to see if there is any built in functionality to do this but I could find anything. Interestingly, I have not seen the problem with paramiko (The output from paramiko is always clean).

I have also tried to find out how bash processes text and control characters, but could not come up with a way to process the file with control characters.

Is there any way to process these control characters?

Edit:
My pexpect code:

```
def change_password(user, ip, password, logfile):

    ssh = pexpect.spawn("ssh -p 21 " + user + "@" + ip)
    # ssh.logfile_read = sys.stdout
    ssh.logfile_read = logfile

    ssh.expect("assword:")
    ssh.sendline(old_password)
    ssh.expect("#")

    ssh.sendline("curl https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=760868")
    ssh.expect("#")
```

Comment: Please post your pexpect code.

Comment: how are you using paramiko? do you ask paramiko to run commands on a pty?

Comment: You might look at the deprecated `ANSI.py` that comes with pexpect. It maintains a "virtual terminal" view of the result.

Comment: @pynexj I do not know what you mean... the official docs do not have any function call related to that.

Comment: you said *"The output from paramiko is always clean."* so wondering how you are using paramiko because these ansi escape code is only for tty/pty.